# Sharing configuration settings between various components in .NET

Tags: .net, configuration, clickonce

I'm aware that similar questions on SO are numerous, but I have a caveat.

The basic premise is predictable: I inherited a product consisting of several components, all of which share a few configuration settings, connection string chief amongst these. Currently these components call a web service with a hashed password in order to retrieve the connection string (blegh), but this is sometimes causing race conditions at Windows startup between the web serivce and NT services requiring configuration values.

I want to create an elegant solution that allows me to share these settings from a single and secure location, i.e. registry or machine.config. Either one of these would be easily implemented given a single deployment environment, but (here's the problem) one of the components is a click-once application.

So in a nutshell, my question is this: How can I create a centralized mechanism for configuration settings that will also be propagated to click-once deployments?

Options I have considered:

- [Linking configuration files via VS](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/15/how-to-share-configuration-files-between-projects.aspx)
- [External config files](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx)

As far as I can tell, both of those solutions depend on the availability of a local copy of a shared config file, which won't work for click-once.

Two things to note about our deployment environment for the click-once application:

- Deployments are always within a corporate LAN network, thus configuration settings such as the connection string are universally applicable.
- Configuration settings that are packaged with the click-once application upon installation are safe to be overridden with subsequent deployment.

Comment: Is my assumption correct that the webservice you are using right now is also hosted on the local machine? You can't include a centralized option?

Comment: Correct, clients cannot guarantee a deployment environment in which a centralized option is available.

Comment: In that case i would suggest that your current implementation is not that bad, It works in most trust environments and is easily expandable. The race conditions can be easily overcome by using a mutex to ensure the order of startup.

Comment: Please explain the mutex solution? Bear in mind one of the services which needs to be sequenced at Windows startup is IIS, in which the web service is hosted (unless this is converted to a WCF service hosted in an NT Service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, i would suggest that the current solution is a decent way since webservices are not sensitive to security issue's and it ensures a centralized solution. To overcome the race condition, you can use mutexes to force the client to wait for the server to come up. Example code:

```
string mutexName = "C01F6FBB-50E9-4BFA-AFBA-209C316AE9FB";
TimeSpan waitInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d);

// Server sample
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // similate some startup delay for the server
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: Good morning!");

        // Do server business, ensure that the mutex is kept alive throughout the server lifetime
        // this ensures that the application can always check whether the server is available or not
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));    
    }
});

// Application sample
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Application: Checking the server...");

    bool mutexOpened = false;

    while (!mutexOpened)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexName))
            {
                mutexOpened = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application: Server is not yet ready....");

            // mutex does not exist yet, wait for the server to boot up
            Thread.Sleep(waitInterval);
        }
    }

    // Server is ready, we can do our application business now
    // note that we dont need to preserve the mutex anymore. 
    // we only used it to ensure that the server is available.
    Console.WriteLine("Application: Good morning to you!");
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps!